# My page load twice when I use ( php redirect with shortlink redirect)

Tags: php

I have develop a website to take a statistical information about specific link first of all

- I make a short_link that point to the that specific  link (using Google Shortlink    API)
- Then that short_link  point to other page in my site that take statistical information  like (IP, Country code , date , time ,.... )
- Then at the end of this page there is a redirect to the destination website (Link)

  ```
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

      $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
       $deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');

       $device=$deviceType;


      $countryid=$this->geoCheckIP($ip);
      $countryid=substr ($countryid["country"],0,2);

      $date = date('Y-m-d');
      $time = date('H:i:s');



      $this->statistical->Addvisit($device,$countryid,$ip,$date,$time);
      redirect($url);
  ```

the above code work correctly and retrieve a correct data 
but some time it execute twice ( especially when there are slow internet connection ) 
and in the second load (execution)  it give an error data (IP, countryid ,...) 
How can I solve that  ???? 
thank you :)

Comment: create a API to convert your shortlink to the correct link, call that method instead, redirect(use_link("YOUR SHORT LINK"));

Comment: Addvisit it function i call it from model (statistical)

Comment: what you mean by create a API to convert your shortlink  ??